# How should I pass json data in the request payload of http post request (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, post, citrus-framework

I have got a **Json data**, which I need to pass into **POST request** using `httpActionBuilder.client(httpClient).post("/API").payload(jsonPayloadHere);`

Is there any way I can pass Json data as a argument in the payload() method above. One way of doing it is passing it as string, which is prone to errors easily(I just don't want to pass it as String, not effective).

My JSON looks like:

```
{
    "Date": "2020-02-25",
    "Id": 1,
    "Names": [
        {
            "firstName": "AB",
            "Cd": 1,
            "surname": "CD"
        }
    ],
    "dateOfBirth": {
        "countryId": 1,
        "DateCD": 1,
        "dateOfBirth": "2010-01-02"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: If you are using spring boot, you can take a look at RestTemplate or spring webclient and pass POJO of this json representation(jackson will take care of serializing and deserializing the json to POJO object and vice versa).

Comment: hi, thanks for helping, however I don't want to deserialize the json into POJO object. I want only to pass JSON into the payload, but I want to avoid store json into string using concat function, it is prone to errors and make it too complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your request body in eg. `payload.json` file and load it with `ClassPathResource` like this:

`httpActionBuilder
     .client(httpClient)
     .post("/API")
     .payload(new ClassPathResource("template/payload.json"));`

Files `payload.json` must be stored in resources directory.